# gzip php style sheets nginx

Tags: nginx, gzip

I have a css sheet generated using PHP, This stylesheet seems to avoid gzip. below is my types within the nginx server, It pretty much hits all of the files excepts a very important generated style sheet. any suggestions?

using google chrome, the php style sheet appears as type: style sheet its a boot_strap. any help?

```
gzip_types
text/plain
text/css
text/js
text/xml
text/javascript
application/javascript
application/x-javascript
application/json
application/xml
application/xml+rss
font/truetype
font/opentype
image/svg+xml
application/x-font-ttf
application/x-font-opentype
application/vnd.ms-fontobject;
```